# Tutorial / reference to launch ACTION_EDIT with image and return image

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm writing an app that uses the camera.  I want to lauch an intent to allow users to annotate the resulting image with lines and text, AND I would like to provide the user with a list of appropriate image editting apps they can use, but I'm coming across these problems:
1. Not all image editting apps appear in the list when I perform this code:

```
editIntent = new Intent();
editIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
Uri imageToEditUri = selectedPhotoLocation;  // Uri of existing photo
String imageToEditMimeType = "image/*";
editIntent.setDataAndType(imageToEditUri, imageToEditMimeType);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(editIntent,"Edit Image"), IMPLICIT_EDIT_IMAGE);

Is there a way to get a list of apps that will respond to Intent.ACTION_EDIT?
```

2. PS Express is the only app I've found that returns the Uri of the editted image in the data.getDate() Uri returned to OnActivityResult(), with other apps the user is forced to save, remember the location, and reselect the editted image.

```
Is there a way to know what apps return the Uri of the image to OnActivityResult()
```

Answer (score 4):

> Not all image editting apps appear in the list when I perform this code

Just because an app implements image editing does not necessarily mean that it is set up to allow third parties to link to their image-editing activities.

> Is there a way to get a list of apps that will respond to Intent.ACTION_EDIT?

If you mean that you want to do this programmatically at runtime, see Jedil's answer.

> Is there a way to know what apps return the Uri of the image to OnActivityResult()

No, except for those applications that have documentation on how developers should integrate with them.

Comment: I'm finding the third answer be painfully true. We're probably going to implement custom return-value logic on a per-external-app basis. Even Google's own apps (I'm looking at you Google Plus) don't seem to work properly. When using a FileProvider, Google Plus simply pops a toast that says "unable to save photo edits" and spins forever. It looks like it's been a problem for over a year.

Comment: @JohnnyLambada: `FileProvider` and Google's apps aren't getting along. It's something I need to figure out a solution for, beyond yelling at Google to get their *bleep*ing act together.

Comment: I can't get Google Plus to correctly edit an image and send it back to my app any which way I try. I've tried FileProvider and a bare file out on the SD card. Nothing seems to work. Sucks because most every phone out there has GP on it, and their image edit software is quite good. I looked for a place to file a bug report for GP app, but can't find one.

Comment: After 9 years, still no solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

First question answer:
try [queryIntentActivities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

```
Intent editIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(editIntent, 0);
```

Comment: You would need to add the rest of the information (e.g., `Uri`, MIME type) to the `Intent` for this to work.